# How to deploy webpack application on tomcat?

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, webpack

I am new to [Webpack module bundler](http://webpack.github.io/). I am making a simple application in AngularJS with Webpack.

My application is running properly by executing command `npm start` which runs in development mode.

Now I want to deploy it on tomcat server. But, when I searched on internet, everyone is saying execute command `npm run deploy` to deploy. (Source: [link](https://github.com/dmachat/angular-webpack-cookbook/wiki/Deploy-to-production))

Is there any way to deploy webpack application on tomcat server?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use webpack with tomcat the simplest way is probably to use webpack to create the packed `.js` file and then serve that out of tomcat.

With the setup described on the page you reference you will grab the `dist/bundle.js` file and have tomcat serve that. Alternatively, you could use something like [gulp-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-webpack) to produce the bundled file for you.